# PowerShell - Output return values into a multi-line text box

Tags: user-interface, powershell, batch-file, psexec

I have a powershell GUI i'm working on. It calls a batch file that uses psexec to uninstall multiple old java installs with $pc argument. When it's called my GUI locks up, however i can see it running in ISE. Is there a way i can forward the output of the batch file to a multiline text box on the GUI so you can see that it is still processing?

TOM: I do not have it outputing to the GUI yet, that is my question. The part of my script that calls it is:

```
if ($unjava=1){
   cmd /c "d:\tool\scripts\fixit\WAITjremover.bat $pc"
}
```

After the script hits this point, i cannot even move the GUI windows, ie Frozen, until after i see the script finish in the output window on the Powershell ISE

Comment: Do you have some example code for how you're currently outputting to the GUI? Might shed some light on why it's locking up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the reason the UI freezes is because you're running the above line in the same thread as the UI. The UI won't be able to re-draw because it isn't getting CPU cycles - all cycles for the thread are going to the cmd call. You're going to need to split up the background execution from the drawing so that they don't interfere with each other.

You may try running the cmd within a job -

```
$j = start-job { param($unjava,$pc); if ($unjava=1) { cmd /c "d:\tool\scripts\fixit\WAITjremover.bat $pc" } } -argumentlist $unjava,$pc
wait-job $j
```

I'm not positive on this, it's possible that the wait-job will halt all execution of the UI while it waits for the job to complete, in which case this is all for naught.

Comment: The UI freezing isn't that big of a deal, if it was a selected option, then user should expect that the process must complete to continue. I mainly would like it to output the... well..DOS echos to a multi-line textbox inside of the GUI

Comment: I would judiciously use get-member on the objects you have at hand to determine their types and properties. If you're using Windows Forms or some other standard UI framework, you should be able to find samples online on adding text to multi-line textbox of that .NET object type. Even if the samples are in C# it should be a fairly easy conversion to PowerShell, because all of the .NET object manipulation will be the same. Ex.: $textbox.Text += "new stuff"

Comment: well, in this situation; i was hoping for something like

$txtBox= {cmd /c "script.bat" >> $txtbox.txt}

obviously not the correct format, but you get the idea

Comment: Still looking for an answer to my original question, but giving Riknik the point for helping me 'unfreeze' the UI.